# JAVA printing correct output with an error [[I@6acbcfc0 in MATRIX-ADDITION

Tags: java, arrays, matrix

I wrote code for adding two matrices with the help of two-dimensional arrays. But after running, it is showing a result with error `[[I@6acbcfc0`. If you know the meaning of `[[I@6acbcfc0`, then please describe it as well. Following is the code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);
    
    System.out.println("Enter dimensions: ");       
    int rows = sc.nextInt();
    int cols = sc.nextInt();
    
    int a[][] = new int [rows][cols];
    int b[][] = new int [rows][cols];
    
    System.out.println("Enter first matrix: ");     
    for (int i = 0; i<rows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j<cols; j++) {
            a[i][j] = sc.nextInt();
        }
    }
    
    System.out.println("Enter second matrix: ");        
    for (int i = 0; i<rows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j<cols; j++) {
            b[i][j] = sc.nextInt();
        }
    } 
    
    int c [][] = new int [rows][cols];
    
    for (int i = 0; i<rows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j<cols; j++) {
            c[i][j] = a[i][j] + b[i][j];
        }
    }
    
    System.out.println("Result is " + c);
    for(int i = 0; i<rows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j<cols; j++) {
            System.out.print(c[i][j] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

}

and the output is

```
Enter dimensions: 
2 2

Enter first matrix: 

1 2

1 2

Enter second matrix: 

1 2

1 2

Result is [[I@6acbcfc0

2 4 

2 4
```

Please help me in removing "[[I@6acbcfc" and if you find any mistake in my code, please correct it so that i can understand it further better. Thank you.

Comment: Hello and welcome. There's no need to HIGHLIGHT every other word.

Comment: Its not an error you are printing c

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I print my Java object without getting "SomeType@2f92e0f4"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29140402/how-do-i-print-my-java-object-without-getting-sometype2f92e0f4)

Comment: @ShubhamSrivastava 'But_ why_ it_ is_ printing_ that_ after_ result?'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are printing c using   `System.out.println("Result is " + c);` so it is being added to output. Just remove that and you are good to go.

You can also try this to print 2D array.

```
System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(c));
```

for printing normal array

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(c));
```

Comment: With the addendum that, weirdly enough, they're using a correct way to print the content of an array right below that.

Comment: yes, how strange is that.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are executing

```
 System.out.println("Result is " + c);
```

where c is `int [][]`

Presumably you want the entire array to be printed out by thus, but this is not behavior that actually exists.

What you see printed is the result of `c.toString()`, which is not defined to be anything useful to you.

If you want the array content printed out, you'll have to write code to print it, element by element.  Which, in fact, you have already done, immediately below.

```
for(int i = 0; i<rows; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j<cols; j++) {
        System.out.print(c[i][j] + " ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

So just remove the `+ c` from the preceding `println` call.